# How to print all possible sequences with intermixed sequence of push and pop operation

Tags: java, algorithm, permutation

Suppose that an intermixed sequence of push and pop operations are performed on a LIFO stack.How to print all possible sequences? I can just judge it's about recursion. For example, if order **1 2 3** is given, output is

> 1 2 3 
>     1 3 2 
>     2 1 3 
>     2 3 1 
>     3 2 1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use Google GUAVA's method https://google.github.io/guava/releases/19.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Collections2.html#orderedPermutations(java.lang.Iterable) to get all possible permutations and then for each permutation reverse the order using https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#reverse(java.util.List)

Comment: Thanks! That problem really puzzles me.